# How to validate date range in Lumen

Tags: laravel, validation, lumen

I want to apply date range validation in Lumen (Laravel) with pagination. The date range as `end_date` can not be smaller than `start_date`.

```
$this->validate($req, [
    'start_date' => 'daterange',
    'end_date' => 'daterange',
]);
```

Comment: What lumen version?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the standard Laravel validation rules from here: [Laravel Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation)

When you want to make sure a date is after a given time or after the date from another field under validation you can use the `after` rule like [shown in the docs here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-after)

```
$this->validate($req, [
    'start_date' => 'required|date',
    'end_date' => 'required|date|after:start_date'
]);
```

Additionally you can define your date format by using the `date_format` rule:

```
'end_date' => 'required|date|after:start_date|date_format:Y-m-d'
```

Comment: I'm glad I helped @viralchampanery. Please select my solution as the accepted answer, by clicking on the check mark beside the post, so it may help others too.